# HTTP response for validation request

Tags: validation, rest, http-status-codes

I've got a service that validates names, that can be used to check whether a username is OK.  It looks something like this:

```
POST http://names.myservice.com/validate 
content-type: application/json
{"name": "Abdul Hideo McDodgycharacter¬§(*&^$%£!"}

=> 200 OK 
{"errors": "contains invalid characters"}
```

So the point of the service is to check the validity of a proposed username, also checking in my db to see whether it's already been taken.  My question is: should the response code be `400 (Bad Request)` when there are validation errors?

If I was building a user API to create users, that's what I'd do when presented with Abdul here, but I'm not. In this case the request is for validation, the input data is acceptable, and the response contains the requested representation, which is a list of errors for the supplied data, so a `200 OK` feels right.  A `400` would indicate my validation request was malformed, and the data to be validated couldn't be identified.

I realise that this isn't very RESTful, because "validate" is basically a verb, so if there's another way to do this that solves my query, please suggest it!

Answer (score 3):

If the request for validation was successful, then `200 (OK)` is the correct response code. As far as endpoints, you can consider

```
POST /validated-names
```

Comment: What if the validation failed?  I'm suggesting that a `200` is also appropriate then, because _the request for validation was successful_.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the request to perform validation was successfully executed, regardless of the output".